# Скрипт работает только после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть произвольное меню. Под ним двигается блок. По наведении на определенный элемент блок плывет к нему. Скрипт для него работает после перезагрузки страницы. Вопрос почему?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var item = document.getElementsByClassName('cur-item')[0];
   $('.wrapper ul li').on('mouseenter',
     function(evt) {
       item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (this.offsetLeft + 100) + 'px)';
     });
 });
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:800px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper ul{
  width:800px;
  height:95px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  width:95px;
  height:95px;
  margin-right:5px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#33a030;
}
.cur-item{
  width:95px;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100px;
  background-color:#33a030;
    
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  will-change: transform;
}
.current{
  background-color:#000!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cur-item"></div>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Может есть другой способ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("#nivolightbox-MA4QP-3941 a.nivolightbox").nivoLightbox({
        effect: "fade",
        theme: "default",
        keyboardNav: true,
        clickOverlayToClose: true,
        errorMessage: "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.",
    });
});
```

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).nivoLightbox is not a function

Comment: Смотрите в консоль браузера на наличие ошибок. И в вашем вопросе и тут http://jsfiddle.net/29t0rL0m/ работает с первого раза.

Comment: Даже если прямо тут код запустить, то тоже с первого раза.

Comment: Есть ошибка. На сайте стоит NivoLightbox. При первой загрузке пишет, что скрипт лайтбокса - не функция. Скрипт формируется по ходу загрузки страницы и вставляется динамически. Код приложу выше. После перезагрузки ошибка пропадает

Comment: Могу ссылку дать на страницу, а то так , наверняка не понятно почему ошибка происходит

Comment: http://sunnysmiledesign.ru/foto-galereya/ и оттуда перейти на дизайн гостиной

Comment: @Александр все работает. Если действительно бывает ошибка, то видимо она в коде nivoLightbox'а.

Comment: Да не, скорее всего там есть загрузчик в теме, появляется колесико и крутится когда на другую страницу переходишь, возможно из-за него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике на ссылку из меню происходит не переход на страницу, а подгрузка страницы аяксом, поэтому слайдер не загружается.

Нужно подгружать nivoLightbox на всех страницах, либо после аякс запроса делать проверку на наличие лайтбокса.

Comment: Проверка, типо есть лайтбокс или нет? Так он есть в любом случае.

Comment: Отключил ajax, все пашет. Спасиб!

Comment: Захожу на страницу http://sunnysmiledesign.ru/disayn-gostinoy-foto-galereya/ , слайдера нет. Открываю в браузере http://sunnysmiledesign.ru/disayn-gostinoy-foto-galereya/ тогда загружается nivo-lightbox.min.js. При клике по ссылке отрабатывате аякс запрос, который не подгружает  контент страницы, но не подгружает js файлы